# Passing string parameters not working in Django

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

`view.py`

> when i test my api with post man ,postman indicate tha this urls do not exist(404 not found) any solution please

> url postman:localhost:8000/photoByCategory/nature/

```
@api_view(['GET'])
@permission_classes((permissions.IsAuthenticated,))
def photo_by_categorie(request, category=False):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        if category:
            photo_by_cat = Photo.objects.filter(category=category)
            serializer = PhotoSerializer(photo_by_cat, many=True)
            return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

`urls.py`

```
re_path(r'photoByCategory/(?:(?P<category>\d+)/)?$', views.photo_by_categorie, name='photo_by_categorie'),
```

Comment: Your URL has `nature` while your regex only accepts numbers at that place.

Comment: Hi, Zaid. Please watch out for typos in your question title as would prevent others from finding you problem in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I guess the problem is with your regex
Try this

```
from django.urls import path, re_path

# Match string after drinks/ prefix
path('photoByCategory/<str:category>/',views.photo_by_categorie),
# Match one or more characters (non-digit regular expression) after drinks/ prefix
re_path(r'^photoByCategory/(?P<category>\D+)/',views.photo_by_categorie),
```

[Here](https://www.webforefront.com/django/accessurlparamstemplates.html) you can find the relevant information.

Note: I have ran first one myself and it works as intended